# Will loading too many ACF Fields cause slow down?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, performance

- I work on a website which uses about 5-8 ACF fields on almost every page (an ACF Fan!). The count goes up to 10-12 fields in the `single.php` of my CPTs.
- I call the ACF fields directly using the `the_field` / `get_field` functions and have used flexible content and hierarchical repeater fields etc.

  1. How much impact would this make on the performance of my website?
  2. How to make them more efficient, and consume less server.
  3. Does using some particular fields over the other have a performance advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer.

The (experienced) performance depends on how powerful your server is, how much simultaneous users are accessing your site etc.

With a dozen ACF-fields, you will most likely not experience any significant performance loss. A typical request to a WP page will often result in dozens of database queries, your 10 additional queries will hardly matter.

If you are worried about performance, you should look into caching the response completely. There are multiple plugins for that, or you could use servers like nginx or varnish that sit in front of your webserver and cache some responses.

Comment: Thank You! I use AWS, and I am working on edtech platform. Server cost due to traffic isn't a concern. I was just wondering whether using ACF is an efficient choice in the long run since I have used it to lay the entire data structure of the website (before there is no going back ;)

Comment: Yes, if you don't overdo it, it's not a problem at all. I know sites that run 70+ queries to ACF fields on any given page, and you don't notice it when you access them in a browser, because it'll only add 0.1-0.3s. Once you add a cache, the difference doesn't matter, as it will only be generated when you flush your cache, update the post / page etc.

Comment: Thank you once again! I am a beginner and was a bit concerned.  I will try to work on caching the response.

Comment: @janh A bit related, but do you have any good resources for optimizing WP speeds in terms of code? Eg "10 tips to make WP faster: 1) Don't use X function".

Comment: @JonathanGuerin There is no magic bullet, I'm afraid, but most sites I've worked on suffered from an overuse of plugins. Bloated wp_options tables (with lots of autoload options) can kill performance, too. I don't think there's a lot of very expensive functions in WP core that you can easily implement more efficiently.